# Pointer position at the time of VSAM START command

Tags: cobol, vsam

I am a bit confused. I know when you START a VSAM file, a pointer is set to a specific record, which will be read by subsequent READ command.

Let's assume that VSAM has records:

```css
100
200
300
400
500
```

When you write:

```css
START filename
 KEY IS GREATER THAN 400
```

It will place pointer at 500. But if you say

```css
START filename
 KEY IS GREATER THAN 600
```

where will the pointer be placed ?

Will it be on 500 or will it be an error.

Also, my understanding is that START will never give an end of file (RETURN CODE 10).

Answer (score 5):

The pointer will not be positioned to any record.

An `INVALID KEY` condition will be raised with `FILE STATUS` `"23"`, indicating `no record found`.

From the 2002 COBOL standard:

> "14.8.37.3 General rules
>
> "7) Following the unsuccessful execution of a START statement, the
>   file position indicator is set to indicate that no valid record
>   position has been established. For indexed files, the key of reference
>   is undefined."